# Dygraphs: no ticks and tick labels on x axis

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have data for 30 minutes with 1 second granularity, time values are in unix timestamp. Dygraph displays no ticks and tick labels on x axis at all, though, when I roll mouse over the line, a legend appears with correct date and time in it. I use the following code, but it doens't help.

```
    axes: {
        x: {
            axisLabelFormatter: function(d) {
                return d.strftime('%H-%M');
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make Dygraph display ticks and tick labels on x axis with my data?

Comment: look here http://dygraphs.com/tests/x-axis-formatter.html

Comment: I saw this example, but I don't understand how to apply it to my situation. I think the answer is to use 'ticker' option, but I can not figure out what is the correct way to do this.

Comment: why don't you paste your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/AlexanderSh/CUgsM/ I know, forming data like this (with new Date() for each record) looks ugly and is bad practice, but this code is generated in script, which generates all the other http code, so it was quick and dirty.

Comment: The problem with your code is that all your dates are in reverse order. Reverse your list (put the first time first) and everything should work. dygraphs logs a warning when CSV inputs are out of order. It should do the same for native format data:

Comment: @danvk thank you very much! It helped! Could you please say, how to get dygraphs logging?

Comment: Just open your browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in Dygraph since it does not display x axis if values are in a reverse order and presented as an array of arrays.
However it seems to be working if data is present as CSV, so just add

```
.reduce(function(a,b){return ""+a+"\n"+b;})
```

to the end of the array sequence.

so your data line will look like the following:

```
[new Date(1373197702 * 1000), 105487872],[new Date(1373197701 * 1000), 105401856] ].reduce(function (a, b) { return ""+a+"\n"+b; }),
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/CUgsM/1/

Comment: This is not a bug -- dygraphs expects data to be in sorted order. This fix "works" because, with CSV inputs, dygraphs will sort the data for you and log a warning about passing in bad data.